# Process.Start in Windows\System32 folder

Tags: c#

Trying to launch a file located in System32 as administrator but it keeps telling me it doesn't exist.

Error: System can't find specified file
Build Target Platform is: x86.
Current OS: Windows 8.1 x64. I'd rather not have 2 different .exes for a 32 and 64 bit os.

```
p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
p.StartInfo.FileName =
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System),"Defrag.exe");
    //above points to c:\windows\system32\defrag.exe
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"c:\ /A";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

I have also tried the following with no luck

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = 
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "sysnative", "Defrag.exe");
```

**Update**

Switched the app from x86 to Any CPU corrected the issue

Comment: Please (always) show the complete exception (ex.ToString()).

Comment: By any chance are you running on a 64 bit version of Windows 7/8?  If so, try setting the build target to 64 bit from Any CPU.  Windows does some strange shuffling of things around using sysnative.  Some files that we "think" are in System32, aren't, because Windows doesn't know which version of the file we mean.  The sysnative, or the alternate.

Comment: What happens if you run the .exe from your bin\Debug (or bin\Release) folder and right-click -> "Run as Administrator"..I think maybe this is a permissions issue?

Comment: @SeanThoman still can't find file and verb runas should launch defrag.exe as admin.

Comment: @DarkBobG current os is 8 x64 but the build is set to x86 as I would like it to be as such so I don't have a build for x86 and x64.

Comment: @Tsukasa But does it work, with the build target set to x64?  That's the only way I can get your code to function in Windows 7 64.

Comment: @DarkBobG switch to x64 and same results. I will test on a Windows 7 x64 box, maybe there is an issue with Win 8.1

Comment: @GrantWinney Switching to Any CPU did the trick

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you are running this code on a 64-Bit Machine. If I remember correctly, the Environment.SpecialFolder.System variable returns C:\Windows\SysWOW64 on a 64-Bit machine. A quick search of the SysWOW64 Folder, and the error message is correct as "Defrag.exe" doesn't exist in the folder.

For test purposes, I would suggest something a bit simpler
    i.e Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\defrag.exe")

Then you can use other variables to build your path based on the System Architecture:


`String processPath = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem 
     ? Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86), "Defrag.exe")
     : Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "Defrag.exe")`

Comment: the path is indeed already pointing to System32 where Defrag.exe is. The application build is set to x86.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Environment.SystemDirectory`:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "defrag.exe");
```