# Create folder in system32 in a 64-bit environment

Tags: c#, windows

What I've tried :

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(
       Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "test"));
```

The folder isn't created and there's not a single exception thrown.

Why doesn't it work and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is WOW64 [file system redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx). Your process is 32 bit and the file is created in the 32 bit system folder, `SysWOW64`. Run the code in a 64 bit process if you want to see the 64 bit system directory. Or use the `sysnative` alias as described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx).

Of course, applications are expected not to create files or directories in the system directory. So another, possible better solution, will be to avoid creating anything in the system directory in the first place.

Comment: I really need to create a specific folder in system32

Comment: How can I access system32 on a procces in 32 bit?
For a Microsoft Word installation

Comment: If you put that last question in your favorite web search engine you'll find another duplicate: [Process.Start in Windows\System32 folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027559/process-start-in-windows-system32-folder). - edit: Microsoft Word already has an installer. Are you sure what you're trying to do is what you should do?

Comment: I very much doubt that you are going about this the right way. I very much doubt that writing to these folders is what you should be doing.