# C# nbtstat process cannot find specified file

Tags: c#, process

I'm trying to get the mac address of our clients using `nbtstat`. I'm using a `System.Diagnostics.Process` to execute the command.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "nbtstat";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-a {0}", principal.Name);
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();
```

Unfortunately that code throws me an exception.

> The system cannot find the file specified.

If the exe file of nbtstat is in System32 folder, it should work without the full path I thought. But I tried it using the full path anyway.

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\nbtstat.exe";
```

The code still throws me the exception. I'm able to use other commands like `ipconfig`, `getmac`, `ping` etc. It's just `nbtstat` which causes the problem. I double checked the directory of `nbtstat.exe`, it's in the right folder. I also tried using `ProcessStartInfo` like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
// set properties like above
Process.Start(info);
```

Also this does not help (it would confuse me if this works but the code above not, because it should be exactly the same, right?).

I'm using Windows Forms and .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: Try building with any cpu

Comment: Ah, great. I'd have never tried that... Thank you :)

Comment: refer http://scottiestech.info/2009/06/20/calling-a-32-bit-system-command-from-a-script-in-x64-windows/, you may need to check how to call a win32 file from win64 env.

Comment: @AnilKumar This link is down :)

Comment: ahh just got it from @VinayPandey answer already +1 from my side.

Comment: @Roman, yeah now it not working, giving timeout :(

Comment: @AnilKumar Up again, thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either swtich to any cpu or check os verison and get the environment path, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21028022/87956